# Delete not deleting the selected post but its deleting the recently(newels) added post

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

My `Update.php` file:

```
<?php ob_start();
 session_start();


//declare the basic variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "bilal";
$password = "super";
$dbname = "coursework";

 //create connection
 $link =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


//check connection
if($link->connect_error){
die ("connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
}

//Security purpose, handiling escape string
  // $crested_by = $_POST ['created_by'];
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $catagory = $_POST['catagory'];
  $contact = $_POST['contact'];
  $comment = $_POST ['description'];
   $ses = $_SESSION['email'];
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $availability = $_POST ['availability'];
  $price = $_POST ['price'];
  $id = $_POST['wow'];
 // $created_by_id = $_SESSION['created_by_id'];

 // $username = $_SESSION['firstname'];
 if (isset($_POST['del'])){
  $deletequery=mysqli_query($link,"DELETE FROM new_post WHERE id='$id'");
  header ("Location: added_posts.php");
   }

    else if(isset($_POST['update'])){

   $sql = "UPDATE new_post SET title='$title', contact='$contact',        availability='$availability', price='$price', comment='$comment' WHERE  id='$id'";
 if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
 echo "awesoke";
  header("Location:added_posts.php");
  }else{
   echo "Error: Sign up Unsuccessfull";
}  
}

$link->close();
 ?>
```

This is my `update.php` file I am showing the `id` inside as `textbox` and the doing where `id = the text field value`. It is deleting but the recently added item deletes like if i have 3 posts id like ( 4, 5, 6) id delete the 6 first then 5 then 4. I am displaying data in bootstrap cards. but every delete button under post it delete the recent one which is recently added.

Comment: print value of `$id` before deleting and check that you are passing proper ID value.

Comment: what is `$_POST['wow']` and how is it gotten? do u really need to show the id's inside text boxes, it can be a hidden post field or you can pass the value through the url

Comment: well i am showing the id of the post in a textfield to make sure that it is correct! and the name of the textfield in wow. so i ust added it as a post and make it equals to id. but still it is deleting the recent post like. first 3rd then if i press again then 2nd and even if i want to delete 1st and click delete from the first card then it deletes the 3rd

Comment: this is my button: ( <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="del">DELETE</button> )

Answer (score 2):

So you're trying to delete the most recent record in your database?

Your problem is the **sql statement** *you have*

```
"DELETE FROM new_post WHERE id='$id'"
```

This is deleting the record in `new_post` where the id  is equal to the id posted from your form.

You must consider that the latest entry in the table will have the **largest 
id**.

So use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM new_post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Attempt 2:**

You want to delete a specific row based on the id?

I suggest you use **[prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)** for security

**Firstly try this:**

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM new_post WHERE id= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['wow']); // can also use $id 
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: No No No!! i am just trying to delete a specific record. like i have made cards and in all cards there is details and every card have delete button. but if i press delete from any card the most recent post delete then if i press agaian the second recent gets delete.

Comment: Okay well you need to make sure your post variables are being assigned properly, echo them out so echo $id

Comment: echo is perfectly correct! i am showing id ina  text field and then the name of the textfield i am using in query like where id= "the name of the text field"

Comment: Then I see nothing wrong with your query "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$id'"

Comment: yup! yup i did! it was method problem in my form

Comment: Well done, close the question. So either accept or create an answer @bilal